# Different styles for tags with the same name <h2>

Tags: html, css

I think this is a real silly question. 
But I really can not find an answer.

I need to give all my h2 tags the border-top element, except my h2 tag that is in my `<header>`.

Now it gives it a big line there and it is going across my header.

I really don't know how to solve this issue that seems so easy.

```
body {
    background-color: AntiqueWhite;
    max-width: 800px;
    font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;

}

h2, h3 {
    font-style: italic;
    color: darkblue;
}

h3 {
    border-top:1px solid #999; padding-top:10px;
}

header {
    background-image: url(pics/bg.jpg);
    height: 140px;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with using CSS classes? That is probably the route I would go.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to be specific.

```
header h2 {
border-top:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `<h2>`'s style and set the border back to it's default, like so:

```
h2 {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}

header h2 {
    border-top: initial;
}
```

Or, and this is the approach I recommend, have your `border-top` in a class. Then, only instances of `<h2>` that have that class will have a border:

```
h2.with_border {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<h2 class="with_border">This has a border!</h2>
<h2>This does not have a border!</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS lets you compose selectors that are more complex; the simplest way of doing this is the descendant selector, which will work for your question. You can write this:

`header h2 { }`

to target any `h2` that is a child (direct or not) of a `header`. For example:

```css
h2 { border-bottom: 1px solid blue; }
header h2 { border-bottom: none; }
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>No border here!</h2>
</header>


<h2>But here there is</h2>
```

You should also do some reading up on how css works; there are all kinds of ways to select elements, including classes and attributes. Which one you use will depend on what you're trying to achieve and how specific you need to be.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stkdkpvw/) for you.

**HTML**

```
<h2>Header One</h2>
<h2>Header Two</h2>
<h2>Header Three</h2>

<header>
  <h2>Header Four</h2>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
h2{
  border-top: 1px solid green;
}

header h2{
  border-top: none;
}
```

Hope this helps.